# Using Django 1.4, How can I save TimeStampedModel objects without automatically updating the modified field?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am in the process of running a Datamigration using Django and South. I have already added a new field to my model with a Schemamigration, and now I am in the process of populating the field for all the objects of that Model.

The problem is that when I call the save() method on my objects in the datamigration, it is automatically updating the modified field that is on each object and all the objects are ending up with the same modified date. I would like to be able to preserve the modified date from before the datamigration if possible.

Currently my datamigration looks like this:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        for w in orm.Writer.objects.all():
            w.type = 'outside'
            if w.managed_by != None:
                if w.managed_by.writer != None:
                    if w.id == w.managed_by.writer.id:
                        w.type = 'client'
            w.save()
```

Is there a way to only save the values in the type field, without updating the modified date?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your object to only change the fields that you desire by using the update() method available for your model's queryset (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once for additional details).

Though the documentation references using this feature for multiple objects, you can filter the update query to only target a single object by restricting to the PK of the object you're working with:

```
orm.Writer.objects.filter(pk=w.pk).update(type='client')
```